# pyqtgraph - move origin of ArrowItem to local center

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm using pyqtgraph to plot tracks of a robot (the path that the bot drove). Now I want to add a marker to the plot to indicate the bots current position and heading. I thought ArrowItem would be the right choice, because it is scale invariant and can be rotated easily. However the local origin of the arrow is at its tip like this

[image]

but I want it to be in the center like this

[image]

How can I do that? I would also appreciate different solutions to this problem.

### Update

After applying eyllansec's code I get some rendering problems. A minimal example (one has to zoom or move the view to disable the auto scaling):

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import time

class CenteredArrowItem(pg.ArrowItem):
    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.translate(-self.boundingRect().center())
        pg.ArrowItem.paint(self, p, *args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = pg.QtGui.QApplication([])  
    window = pg.GraphicsWindow(size=(1280, 720))
    window.setAntialiasing(True)
    tracker = window.addPlot(title='Tracker')

    while True:
        for i in range(300):         
            arrow = CenteredArrowItem(angle=i, headLen=40, tipAngle=45, baseAngle=30)   
            arrow.setPos(i / 300, i / 300)
            tracker.addItem(arrow)
            app.processEvents()
            time.sleep(0.02)
            tracker.removeItem(arrow)
```

As you may noticed I'm adding and removing the arrow each iteration. This is because `arrow.setStyle(angle=i)` is not working as it does not update the rotation of the arrow (probably a bug).

Comment: It provides the code that generates the first cursor, so it is easier to convert it to the second

Comment: @eyllansec I'm not sure what you mean but the creation of the arrow is straight forward `a=pyqtgraph.ArrowItem(...)`. I just want the origin of its local coordinate system at its center instead of its tip.

Comment: The problem that you are referring to is that jump that occurs at the end of the turn?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that you have to zoom out or move the view so that auto scale is disabled

Comment: ok, I understood the problem, edit your question and add that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to overwrite the paint method of ArrowItem and move the QPainter:

```
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

class MyArrowItem(pg.ArrowItem):
    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.translate(-self.boundingRect().center())
        pg.ArrowItem.paint(self, p, *args)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

w = QtGui.QMainWindow()
p = pg.PlotWidget()
p.showGrid(x = True, y = True, alpha = 0.3)
w.show()
w.resize(640, 480)
w.setCentralWidget(p)
w.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Arrow')


a = pg.ArrowItem(angle=-160, tipAngle=60, headLen=40, tailLen=40, tailWidth=20, pen={'color': 'w', 'width': 3},  brush='r')
b = MyArrowItem(angle=-160, tipAngle=60, headLen=40, tailLen=40, tailWidth=20, pen={'color': 'w', 'width': 3})

a.setPos(10,0)
b.setPos(10,0)

p.addItem(a)
p.addItem(b)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

As shown in the following figure, the red arrow is the default `ArrowItem`, and the blue is the offset, both are located in the same position with respect to the plot.

[image]

**Update:**

The problem is caused by the method that rotates the item used as the center of coordinates using the center of transformations by default, that is to say the (0, 0), we must move it:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import time

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
from pyqtgraph import functions as fn

class CenteredArrowItem(pg.ArrowItem):
    def setStyle(self, **opts):
        # http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/ArrowItem.html#ArrowItem.setStyle
        self.opts.update(opts)

        opt = dict([(k,self.opts[k]) for k in ['headLen', 'tipAngle', 'baseAngle', 'tailLen', 'tailWidth']])
        tr = QtGui.QTransform()
        path = fn.makeArrowPath(**opt)
        tr.rotate(self.opts['angle'])
        p = -path.boundingRect().center()
        tr.translate(p.x(), p.y())
        self.path = tr.map(path)
        self.setPath(self.path)

        self.setPen(fn.mkPen(self.opts['pen']))
        self.setBrush(fn.mkBrush(self.opts['brush']))

        if self.opts['pxMode']:
            self.setFlags(self.flags() | self.ItemIgnoresTransformations)
        else:
            self.setFlags(self.flags() & ~self.ItemIgnoresTransformations)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = pg.QtGui.QApplication([])  
    window = pg.GraphicsWindow(size=(1280, 720))
    window.setAntialiasing(True)
    tracker = window.addPlot(title='Tracker')

    while True:
        for i in range(300):         
            arrow = CenteredArrowItem(angle=i, headLen=40, tipAngle=45, baseAngle=30)   
            arrow.setPos(i / 300, i / 300)
            tracker.addItem(arrow)
            app.processEvents()
            time.sleep(0.02)
            tracker.removeItem(arrow)
```

Comment: It kinda works, but I have rendering problems when the arrow is moving and rotating in a fixed viewbox (see [here](https://pasteboard.co/HbrCaZ5.png))

Comment: @Timo 
Please edit your question and add the necessary code so that you can reproduce your error and propose a better solution. To that in SO we call it [mcve]

Comment: @Timo Try my new solution.

Comment: looks like we ended up with the same solution :) Thanks

Comment: @Timo I just realize that you answered it before.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the source code of pyqtgraph I ended up with a special function that suits my needs. I apply the translation when creating the arrow path, instead when rendering it. Fortunately this also solves the roation bug (for whatever reason).

Example:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import time
import pyqtgraph.functions

class CenteredArrowItem(pg.ArrowItem):
    def setData(self, x, y, angle):
        self.opts['angle'] = angle
        opt = dict([(k, self.opts[k]) for k in ['headLen', 'tipAngle', 'baseAngle', 'tailLen', 'tailWidth']])
        path = pg.functions.makeArrowPath(**opt)
        b = path.boundingRect()
        tr = pg.QtGui.QTransform()              
        tr.rotate(angle)
        tr.translate(-b.x() - b.width() / 2, -b.y() - b.height() / 2)  
        self.path = tr.map(path)
        self.setPath(self.path)
        self.setPos(x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = pg.QtGui.QApplication([])  
    window = pg.GraphicsWindow(size=(1280, 720))
    window.setAntialiasing(True)
    tracker = window.addPlot(title='Tracker')

    arrow = CenteredArrowItem(headLen=40, tipAngle=45, baseAngle=30)   
    tracker.addItem(arrow)
    tracker.addItem(pg.InfiniteLine(pos=(0,0), angle=45))
    center = pg.ScatterPlotItem([], [], brush='r')
    tracker.addItem(center)

    while True:
        for i in range(300):
            arrow.setData(i, i, i)     
            center.setData([i], [i])    
            app.processEvents()
            time.sleep(0.02)
```